# Reading latitude and longitude from database with Oracle ADF

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, oracle-adf

Using Google Maps api v3, I am trying to reconstruct polylines (and other shapes) on a map when my (.jsf) page loads.  The points of the polyline are stored in an Oracle database.  I have tried passing both a XML and a JSON file to some javascript code that will generate the points on the map.  However, Oracle ADF does not open the file but instead opens a 'loopback script'.

Is there a particular configuration that needs to be set in order to achieve this?  Or am I going about this all wrong?  Is there an alternative way to reconstruct the shapes on a map from the database using Oracle ADF?

I will be grateful for any guidance or direction.

Comment: How are you passing the XML or JSON file?

Comment: Via a url. I understand that I can't provide a local file path due to security restrictions which prevent local access.  So I am trying to pass the file's path on the web server as a url:                                               $.get("/mjs-ViewController-context-root/faces/markers.json", function(data) {
              alert("in getjson");
              console.log(data);
              // data is a JavaScript object now. Handle it as such                      
               });

Answer (score 0):

you are using oracle adf's MAP component or google map,
see this ,hope it will help
https://blogs.oracle.com/middleware/entry/integrating_google_maps_with_adf

Comment: Thanks Ashish.  I am using Google Maps v3 javascript api.  I am trying to load some shapes when the page first loads.  Any suggestions on the best way to do this?  The lat and lng of the shapes are stored in the database.  But I don't know how to pass that to the javascript to create the shapes on initialise of the page.